# ¿Como puedo ejecutar controladores dentro de una funcion en angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, controller

alguna posibilidad de ejecutar controladores en o una función?

ejemplo:

```
$scope.send = function(){
controller1
controller2
 };
```

Mi ideas es incorporar un 'ng-click="send";' aun botón en la cual ejecute la tarea, saludos.

Comment: Hola @HernanHumaña, por favor, reformula tu pregunta y por un ejemplo específico de lo que tratas/quieres hacer. Te invito a revisar [este tema](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: no creo que sea posible, plantea mejor tu pregunta para saber exactamente que quieres hacer y darte una mejor solución.

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres ejecutar varios controllers? ... ¿Que tratas de hacer? Correr dos funciones....pienso que la mejor forma no es usar controladores, has pensado en servicios?

Answer (score 1):

Un controller, para ponerlo de una manera simplificada, es un fragmento de código que se ejecuta cuando una directiva se compila. Es por esto que en los controllers puedes acceder al `$scope` que es una característica de los elementos del DOM, no de los controllers en particular.

Esta es la configuración de `ng-controller`

```
var ngControllerDirective = [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    controller: '@',
    priority: 500
  };
}];
```

Si quieres que se ejecuten dos controllers al llamar una función solo tienes que incluir dos elementos que tengan `ng-controller` y usar `ng-if` para que estos se incluyan en el DOM

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ParentCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.mostrarFragmentos = false;

    $scope.habilitar = function() {
      $scope.mostrarFragmentos = true;
    };
  })
  .controller('Controller1', function($scope) {
    $scope.nombre = 'Controller1';

    alert('Controler1');
  })
  .controller('Controller2', function($scope) {
    $scope.nombre = 'Controller2';

    alert('Controler2');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
  <button ng-click="habilitar()">Mostrar controllers</button>
  <div ng-if="mostrarFragmentos">
    <div ng-controller="Controller1">
      {{nombre}}
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="Controller2">
      {{nombre}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Es importante que uses `ng-if` y no `ng-show` ya que el segundo sólo oculta el elemento mientras que el primero lo elimina o lo añade en el DOM provocando una nueva compilación de la directiva y por ende una nueva ejecución del código del controller.

Obviamente sólo debes hacer esto si estás intentando incluir fragmentos de funcionalidades completas, de otra forma puedes mover la lógica que quieres ejecutar al método en particular a un sólo controller y hacerlo todo desde ahí

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('SimpleCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.mostrar = false;
    $scope.name1 = 'Controller1';
    $scope.name2 = 'Controler2';

    $scope.habilitar = function() {
      $scope.mostrar = true;

      alert('Codigo a ejecutar');

    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="SimpleCtrl">
  <button ng-click="habilitar()">Mostrar</button>
  <div ng-show="mostrar">
    <div>{{name1}}</div>
    <div>{{name2}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-click` no funciona así. El controlador contiene funciones que se pueden llamar de `ng-click`. Por ejemplo:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <button ng-click="func()">Clic</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.func = function(){
        alert('Hola!')
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrobe0709/uLohskm3/5/)

Pon la tarea dentro de la función que es dentro del controlador.